# Git deletes and re-adds lines to file

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git` to maintain revisions of a book that I'm writing in LaTeX.  For some reason, `git` seems to delete and re-add lines to the source file.  I added forty or so lines to my .tex file, but somehow git thinks that 4242 lines were added and 4203 lines were deleted.

```
"4242 insertions(+), 4203 deletions(-)"
```

In reality, I deleted nothing, and just added 40 lines.  What could be causing this behavior?

Thanks for the help.  Let me know if any other information could be helpful.  I'm running OS X 10.9, and using TeXShop to edit my files, if this could be relevant.

Comment: Can you provide steps so we can try reproducing the issue?

Comment: Check your [line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Comment: or use `git diff -w`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, Ilya.

The original file was created on a Windows machine, and indeed had different line endings.  Running `git config core.autocrlf input` in the directory of the repository fixed the issue.